# AngularJS Ng-Click directive not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple code segment that was meant to work along with AngularJS, but it simply does not.

```
<form ...> ...
<div class="fieldcontain option-handler" style="display: none;" ng-controller="DynamicTable as table">
    <label for="opcoes">
        Opcoes
    </label>

    <ul class="one-to-many">
        <pre>{{table.rows}}</pre>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>Enunciado</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows">
              <td><input type="text" name="questoes[${i}].opcoes[{{row}}].enunciado" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" name="questoes[${i}].opcoes[{{row}}].score" /></td>
              <td><input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="table.delRow()" /></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="table.addRow()" />
    </ul>
</div>
...
</form>
```

The `{{table.rows}}` excerpt works fine, just as well as the `ng-repeat="row in table.rows"` directive. Both `ng-click` directives don't work, though. Even when I tried changing it to `ng-click="alert('Hello, World!');"` it did not work. Here's the script code that should be ran:

```
var app = angular.module("DynamicForm", []);

app.controller("DynamicTable", function(){
  this.rows = [0];
  this.addRow = function() {
    this.rows.push(this.rows.length);
    alert("Added row" + (this.rows.length - 1).toString());
  };
  this.delRow = function() {
    this.rows.splice(-1, 1);
  };
});
```

It generates a row for the table, with the right value for `{{row}}` and `{{table.rows}}` displays correctly within `<pre>`.

This is ran within a Grails 2.4.4 `.gsp` file, with AngularJS 1.3.15.

Comment: [It works for me as expected. Check out the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ILuw4gcaOj5d93ekgAqK?p=preview).

Comment: I also tried a demo before integrating it. I think the problem itself resides on Grails itself... Oh, how I hate it right now.

Comment: Since you aren't using a `<form>` it doesn't make sense to use an `<input>`.. try using a `<button ng-click="table.addRow()">Add</button>`

Comment: How would `ng-click` be related to Grails?

Comment: Actually, this excerpt lies within a form.

Comment: Show us the full code, it could be related how scopes are nested, Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bCGlGbZM1Mil8YjxM7h0